# Function returning cursor in PL/SQL - close it on Java's side or PL/SQL's side?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jdbc, plsql

I am calling a stored function in PL/SQL using Java that returns a `REF CURSOR`:

```
FUNCTION getApprovers RETURN approvers_cursor IS
    approvers approvers_cursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN approvers FOR
        select * from role where role_name = 'APPROVER';
    RETURN approvers;
END;
```

If I close the cursor before the `RETURN approvers`

```
CLOSE approvers;
RETURN approvers;
```

I get a warning in Java - `Cursor is Closed`.

It seems that I cannot close the cursor in the PL/SQL stored function. Where then does the closing of the cursor take place?

Comment: You need to call `ResultSet.close()` after you're done with it.

Comment: Resultsets *are* cursors; it'd be the same as if you executed that `select` query directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of fact, `ResultSet`s *are* Cursors.

```
 //JAVA                            //PL/SQL
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
            "select * from role where role_name = ?");
 ps.setString(1, "APPROVER");
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); //OPENS the cursor
 while(rs.next()) {                //FETCHES next row from cursor
    //Handle resultset
 }
 rs.close();                       //CLOSES the cursor
```

Of cause since Java 7 you could do this with try-with-resource and hide the close() calls - but for clarity of what equals what written old-style here